# How to compile multiple go files in vscode launch.json?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

If I have several go files that need to be in the main package, how can I specify them to be compiled in the launch.json? I would refactor them into packages. But this project is resisting.

i.e. To run them on the command line, I have to use:

```
go run main.go stuff.go other.go
```

How would I include that in the launch.json file?

```
{
    "name": "Launch myprog",
    "type": "go",
    "request": "launch",
    "mode": "debug",
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/cmd/myprog/main.go",
     "args": ["param"]
},
```

I've tried the obvious ways. I would like to do some debugging.

So... How do I specify in launch.json to compile the package in the folder and not just one specific file?

If `go run main.go` is equivalent to `"program": "${workspaceRoot}/cmd/myprog/main.go"`

Then, `go run .` is equivalent to what? `"program": "${workspaceRoot}/cmd/myprog/[?????]"`

Because the obvious didn't work for me.

Thanks

Comment: Go build/run doesn't operate at the file level, it operates at the package level.

Comment: [The documentation is clear](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies), the parameter to `go build` is a *package*. Your example on the command line *should* be `go run .`.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and forget that there is a `go run` command. It's not what you think it should be used for, it doesn't do what you think it does and it is impossible to get right for novices.

Comment: I understand the file vs package thing... But my question is simpler than that. Assuming "go run ."  on the command line compiles *.go in the package "main" folder... What would be the equivalent for the  "program" line in the launch.json file above? Because "${workspaceRoot}/cmd/myprog/" doesn't work.

Comment: @PrecisionPete `launch.json` is for debugging purpose, if your purpose is to run the command like `go run` automatically in VSCode, why not use [tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) instead?

Comment: I'm not using go run at all. It's just for the example. It's the launch.json syntax I am struggling with. Because I need to debug a package with more than one go file in the main package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must have been some other problem with my system. Because at some point it all just started working...  Though I am also now using the nightly version of the plugin `golang.go-nightly`. It fixed the missing root debug feature beautifully...

This now works fine...

```
{
   "name": "Prog",
   "type": "go",
   "request": "launch",
   "mode": "debug",
   "program": "${workspaceRoot}/src/cmd/prog/",
   "args": [""]
},
```

Answer (score 6):

Using "program": "." worked for me:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch Package",
      "type": "go",
      "request": "launch",
      "mode": "auto",
      "program": ".",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are mixing some concepts in your question, so let me try to answer step by step:

- In **vscode** the `launch.json` file is created automatically by vscode to help it on debugging, it is not part of the go language and it does not define how your application will run or will be compiled. For more reference take a look at [How To Debug Go Code with Visual Studio Code](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/debugging-go-code-with-visual-studio-code).
- **Compile** your application (`go build`) means that all the files related to a specific package will be transformed in a binary. Take a look in [this article](https://www.callicoder.com/golang-packages/) to understand how the packages are linked to your application compile.
- **Run** your application can be done using `go run` which will have almost the same effect as compiling except that this command does not generate your final shareable binary file. Check [go run vs go build](https://hackthedeveloper.com/go-run-vs-go-build-go-tools/)

Now, **regarding to your question**, if you need to enable the proper debugging on vscode, take a look on [gopls-vscode](https://go.dev/blog/gopls-vscode-go), but if your code is not compiling because of dependencies on other files/packages then take a look on the tutorial about packages mentioned above.

I hope that I can give you some help.

Comment: I appreciate your detailed answer. But you missed my actual question. Would you mind taking a look at it again? The program is fine. It's the launch.json syntax I am missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The way this worked for me:

1. Run `go mod init` inside the package directory to start a module. This way `go build` works without specifying the .go files
2. In the `launch.json` for your project, set the value of `program` field to the root directory of the package, without specifying any source file i.e. in your case, it would be `"program": "${workspaceRoot}/cmd/myprog/"`

Answer (score 0):

Mulitple go files with **func main()** in the same folder is convinient for simple code snippents.

You cannot use **go build** on that folder. Go will give an error:

**main redeclared in this block**

But you can run individual files using command

**go run file.go**

To run single file in VSCode you have to add **Launch file** configuration to VSCode

1. Press Gear next to Run triangle button **Open 'launch.json'**
2. In the lower right part of the screen appears button **Add configuration**. Press it.
3. Select '**{} Go: Launch file**' option from the list.

Added new configuration would be:

```
        {
            "name": "Launch file",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "debug",
            "program": "${file}"
        },
```

4. Save launch.go
5. To run your file select '**Launch file**' in the drop down list next to Run triangle button.